# JBOSS-CLI How to change or add a slot to a module dependency for as.weld?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

In the  element of a module.xml I want to add (or update) and slot attribute for a module.

Can you do this with jboss-cli?

More specifically:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.jboss.as.weld">
<!-- stuff ommitted --> 
    <dependencies>
        <!-- stuff ommitted --> 

        <module name="javax.faces.api" />  <!--I want to add the attr slot="blah-blah-1.2.3" to this element --> 

        <!-- stuff ommitted -->
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

I have a wonky SED way to do this.  But is there a way I can do this with JBOSS CLI (or other tool) in a fashion were I don't have to rely on text search & replace?

Answer (score 0):

We cant add/update module slot for module you can use below CLI command:

```
 module --slot=1.1 add  --name=module.name --resources=/path/to/JAR_Files/FileName.jar
```

Comment: I don't want to add a new module.    I merely want to tweak an existing module.xml file.

Comment: I am afraid then, I guess there is no cli command through which you can update module.